# How to add elements to array on multiple div clicks in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to come up with a simple solution on clicking multiple divs that represent their own values as days (Mon-Sun). I should be able to click on more than one div to represent the occurring days for the scheduled class that would take place, I feel it would be easier to make use of check boxes but I'm trying my best to avoid that. Any ideas or examples would be really appreciated.

[image]

****what I have:****

```
function ClassModal(){
   const [recurringDate, setRecurringDate] = useState([]);

   render(
 <div className="mt-3 ml-2 flex">
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Sun</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Mon</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Tue</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Wed</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Thu</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Fri</p>
      <p className="outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300">Sat</p>
 </div>
 )
}
```

****Expected Array Output****

```
recurringDate = ['Mon','Tue','Sun'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
import { useState } from "react"

function ClassModal() {
let [days, setRecurringDate] = useState([
    { day: "Sun", checked: false },
    { day: "Mon", checked: false },
    { day: "Tue", checked: false },
    { day: "Wed", checked: false },
    { day: "Thu", checked: false },
    { day: "Fri", checked: false },
    { day: "Sat", checked: false }
])

const handleDaySelect = (item) => {
    let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(days))
    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (item.day === temp[i].day) {
            temp[i].checked = !item.checked
        }
    }
    setRecurringDate(temp)
}

return (
    <div className="mt-3 ml-2 flex">
        {days.map(item =>
            <p onClick={() => handleDaySelect(item)} className={`checked-${item.checked} outline-none shadow m-1 text-sm transform hover:scale-103 cursor-pointer transition duration-400 ease-in-out hover:border-primarygreen-500 p-2 rounded-lg border border-silver-300`}>{item.day}</p>
        )}
    </div>
)

}

export default ClassModal
```

And then somewhere in your CSS you can do this color them when they are checked

```
.checked-true{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```